# Differences between `import module` and `from package import module`

Tags: python

I've been learning me some dynamic 'plugin loading' for python and noticed a not really problematic but rather an interesting difference between `import module` and `from package import module`.

I've created a test script consisting of four files (resembles my own setup for what I want to achieve)

The file tree looks like this:

- test (main package)

  - sup (package, plugin folder)

    - __init__.py
    - uber.py (plugin)
  - __init__.py
  - bar.py ('main'-program)
  - foo.py (object that needs dynamically added functionality)
  - poo.py (decorator)

poo.py:

```
from test import foo

def decorate(method):
    print "before:", method.__name__ in dir(foo.Foo)
    setattr(foo.Foo, method.__name__, method)
    print "after :", method.__name__ in dir(foo.Foo)
    return method
```

foo.py:

```
import os

class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.__loadplugins("sup")

    @classmethod
    def __loadplugins(cls, plugindir):
        for f in os.listdir(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), plugindir)):
            if f.endswith(".py"):
                __import__(("%s.%s" % (plugindir, f))[0:-3])
```

uber.py:

```
from test import poo

@poo.decorate
def aFunction(self, anArg):
    print anArg
```

I have two versions of bar.py, this one does not work:

```
import foo

f = foo.Foo()

f.aFunction("print goes here") # pylint: disable-msg=E1101
```

This one does work:

```
from test import foo

f = foo.Foo()

f.aFunction("print goes here") # pylint: disable-msg=E1101
```

The only difference between the two bars is the import. One is relative the other one is not. But the relative one does not work, and the absolute one does work. Is there anyone who can replicate this on his machine and could give some kind of explanation of why it is happening?

**update**
Thought it would be useful to also note my python version:
Using normal python release 2.7.2 x86

**update**
Output of the 'wrong' bar.py:

```
before: False
after : True
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Daan\workspace\python\mytests\src\test\bar.py", line 6, in <module>
    f.aFunction("print goes here") # pylint: disable-msg=E1101
AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'aFunction'
```

Output of the 'correct' bar.py:

```
before: False
after : True
print goes here
```

Comment: Try adding an empty file to your test directory named `__init__.py`

Comment: They are there. Bit lazy to put them in that List. But specially for you I'll add them.

Comment: What do you mean by saying that first one doesn't work? If you see an exception, please include backtrace.

Comment: @subdir done, it is quite a standard error message. Hope this clarifies this a bit more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you are inside 'test' directory and have environment variable PYTHONPATH=.. (so you can do both 'import foo' and 'from test import foo').

In this case foo and test.foo are two different modules, loaded separately (in spite of the fact that they are loaded from the same file).

'decorate' function from test.poo module adds method to class 'Foo' that lives in test.foo (first line of poo.py: "from test import foo"), at the same time 'Foo' class from foo module remains unchanged.

Comment: Yes, your first assumptions are correct. From within Eclipse There is a 'src' directory which is in the pythonpath. test is a package and I run the bar.py as a python-run.

Comment: Ok, so I guess I answered your question?

Comment: I have to test them first, haven't got time to try all answers yet :-)

Comment: I indeed was mixing up PYTHONPATH's. My 'test' package was residing in a source dir called src. I was running from within test. but src was also added to the pythonpath. I have now restructured my code/layout and now it works just fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How are you executing bar.py? I am assuming you are going to run it as a package, because that's how you designed it. Or else, `from test import foo` in the second version of bar.py doesn't make much sense as `test` would not be recognized by bar.py unless it is run as a package.

Have a look at the python docs for [Intra-package references](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references). They talk mainly about two kinds of references. Say, you are trying to import uber.py from foo.py. One way to do this is by, explicit relative reference of the kind `from .sup import uber`. Another way to do this, is by absolute reference and this would be of the form `from test.sup import uber` or `import test.sup.uber`

It looks like you are using absolute references through out except in `foo.py`. Here, you are effectively calling `__import__('sup.uber')` where as it should have been `__import__('test.sup.uber')`. I am not sure if this is what is causing the error that you reported, but I was able to get both versions of bar.py to run using,

I got both versions of `bar.py` to run by using this in `foo.py`:

```
__import__(("%s.%s" % ('test.'+plugindir, f))[0:-3])
```

Also, how are you running bar.py as a package? One way to do this would be to include a `import test.bar` line in a script outside the `test` dir and then run it.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your questions:

> Is there anyone who can replicate this on his machine and could give some kind of explanation of why it is happening?

Yes. :-)

Somewhat longer:

Yes - I was able to reproduce it.

Here my explanation:

In the first case (where the error occurs), python includes the module `foo` twice (you can check that easily using a print statement).  The class `Foo` is created a second time, the `aFunction` is added to the second incarnation - still the main program uses the first.

In the second case, the module `foo` is only read in once - and therefore the `Foo` class exists only once.  The same incarnation of the class is used adding the `aFunction` and in the main.

The reason of importing the file twice is IMHO somewhat strange arrangement of modules.  Looks that for python the internal used path / name for the `foo` module differs in the first example.

(I used a lot of `print` of `id(foo.Foo)` and `globals()` to get this sorted out.)